# Using however in the mid sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Please correct me if I am wrong.
e.g. John is unable to attend the event however his friend will attend.

Answer (score 1):

Some writers (and some teachers) like to maintain a distinction between a coordinating conjunction "but"

> John is unable to attend the event, but his friend will attend.

And an adverb "however".  If "however" is an adverb, then it can be used mid sentence, provided you don't create a sentence with two independent clauses:

> John is unable to attend the event however hard he tries.

But you should punctuate into two sentences (or join with a semicolon) if there are two clauses.

> John is unable to attend the event. However, his friend will attend.

Not everyone obeys this "rule", but if you are writing for school it may be a good idea to be aware of it.

Comment: I would usually put a comma before and after the word "however", rather than breaking it into two sentences. But the two sentence solution is not incorrect. It might even be better.